# Magento 2.1 category list.phtml shows syntax error from template

Tags: php, syntax-error, magento2

I am getting this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH),
>   expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) in
>   /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/nego/nego_default/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
>   on line 130

list.phtml shows this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
 */
?>
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><div><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('We can\'t find products matching the selection.') ?></div></div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
    <?php
    if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $image = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $image = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }
    /**
     * Position for actions regarding image size changing in vde if needed
     */
    $pos = $block->getPositioned();
    ?>
    <div class="products wrapper <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?> products-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?>">
        <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
        <ol class="products list items product-items">
            <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
                <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
                    <div class=" product-item-images">
                            <?php
                            $newFromDate = $_product->getNewsFromDate();
                            $newToDate = $_product->getNewsToDate();                
                            $now = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");
                            // Get the Special Price
                            $specialprice = $_product->getSpecialPrice(); 
                            // Get the Special Price FROM date
                            $specialPriceFromDate = $_product->getSpecialFromDate();
                            // Get the Special Price TO date
                            $specialPriceToDate = $_product->getSpecialToDate();
                            // Get Current date
                            if ($specialprice&&(($specialPriceFromDate <= $now && $specialPriceToDate >= $now) || (($specialPriceFromDate <= $now && $specialPriceFromDate != NULL) && $specialPriceToDate  == ''))){
                            $_savePercent = 100 - round(($_product->getSpecialPrice() / $_product->getPrice())*100);
                            echo "<span class='hot-sale'>-".$_savePercent."%</span>";
                            }else{
                            if((($newFromDate <= $now && $newToDate >= $now) || (($newFromDate <= $now && $newFromDate != NULL) && $newToDate == NULL))) {
                            ?>
                            <div class="label-pro-new"><span><?php echo __('new!') ?></span></div>
                            <?php
                            }
                            }
                        ?>  
                        <?php
                        $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
                        if ($pos != null) {
                            $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                                . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
                        }
                        ?>
                        <?php // Product Image ?>
                        <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
                            <?php echo $productImage->toHtml(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-item-details">
                        <?php
                            $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                        ?>
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                            <a class="product-item-link"
                               href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
                            </a>
                        </strong>
                       <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType); ?>
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?>


                         <?php if ($showDescription):?>
                            <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                                <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                   class="action more"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Learn More') ?></a>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <div class="product-item-actions"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                            <div class="add-to-cart-primary"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                    <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                    <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
                                        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                                        <button type="submit"
                                                title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                                                class="tocart">
                                            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </form>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php echo($iterator == count($_productCollection)+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {}
            }
        }
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

All other pages works. But the category pages shows error.

Comment: Possibly if you used less `<?php ... ?>` when they are not needed and some sensible code indentation the error would make itself more obvious

Comment: The error means you have attempted to close the foreach before closing all the IF's that exist inside the foreach

Comment: This if `<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>` does not seem to have an associated `<? endif; ?>`

Comment: Tried inserting <? endif; ?> but no change.

Comment: Then check all the other IF's have been properly closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't close "if" statement started in line 111. Just add it after line 123.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
 */
?>
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><div><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('We can\'t find products matching the selection.') ?></div></div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
    <?php
    if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $image = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $image = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }
    /**
     * Position for actions regarding image size changing in vde if needed
     */
    $pos = $block->getPositioned();
    ?>
    <div class="products wrapper <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?> products-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?>">
        <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
        <ol class="products list items product-items">
            <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
            <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
                <div class=" product-item-images">
                    <?php
                    $newFromDate = $_product->getNewsFromDate();
                    $newToDate = $_product->getNewsToDate();
                    $now = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");
                    // Get the Special Price
                    $specialprice = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
                    // Get the Special Price FROM date
                    $specialPriceFromDate = $_product->getSpecialFromDate();
                    // Get the Special Price TO date
                    $specialPriceToDate = $_product->getSpecialToDate();
                    // Get Current date
                    if ($specialprice&&(($specialPriceFromDate <= $now && $specialPriceToDate >= $now) || (($specialPriceFromDate <= $now && $specialPriceFromDate != NULL) && $specialPriceToDate  == ''))){
                        $_savePercent = 100 - round(($_product->getSpecialPrice() / $_product->getPrice())*100);
                        echo "<span class='hot-sale'>-".$_savePercent."%</span>";
                    }else{
                        if((($newFromDate <= $now && $newToDate >= $now) || (($newFromDate <= $now && $newFromDate != NULL) && $newToDate == NULL))) {
                            ?>
                            <div class="label-pro-new"><span><?php echo __('new!') ?></span></div>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
                    if ($pos != null) {
                        $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                            . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php // Product Image ?>
                    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
                        <?php echo $productImage->toHtml(); ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="product-item-details">
                    <?php
                    $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                    ?>
                    <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                        <a class="product-item-link"
                           href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
                        </a>
                    </strong>
                    <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType); ?>
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
                    <?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?>


                    <?php if ($showDescription):?>
                        <div class="product description product-item-description">
                            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                            <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_productNameStripped ?>"
                               class="action more"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Learn More') ?></a>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <div class="product-item-actions"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                        <div class="add-to-cart-primary"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                            <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
                                <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                                <button type="submit"
                                        title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                                        class="tocart">
                                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                </button>
                            </form>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php echo($iterator == count($_productCollection)+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {}
            }
        }
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that was just what i needed!

Comment: Get some IDE and you will easy catch mistakes like that.

Comment: Thank you. I will do that in the future, annoying that i have to fix mistakes done by professionals in a purchased theme..